# Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found - CakePHP & PHPExcel

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel, cakephp-2.2

**Background**

I have issues using PHPExcel's IOFactory in my app. My PHPExcel helper works if I want to generate an excel document from scratch (my app creates about 20 excel sheets per week, with no issues).

**Why do you need It?**

I need to now combine some sheets (uploaded and generated to a general sheet and then send that off to who-ever. Problem is that all the sheets are generated by a different person. So  they upload all these sheets to the app, and it combines the sheets and sends it out.

**What's the problem then?**

In my `PHPExcelHelper.php` file, I've added the following function:

```
public function createMasterFile($ExcelFile) {
    $MasterFile = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($ExcelFile);
    return $MasterFile;
}
```

This is basically just supposed to take a file, to which it will add all the other files as spreadsheets. I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801732/combine-two-or-more-xls-files-as-worksheets-phpexcel) question as a guide.

However, it throws the following error:

```
Error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found
```

This tells me that it can't find that class (*duh*) and that I need to include it.

**What have you tried?**

I've tried to add it directly by adding `require_once('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');` to the end of the `PHPExcel.php` file located in the `Vendors`-folder. No luck.

Then I tried adding it to my `loadEssentials()`-function in my `PHPExcelHelper.php`-file, which was like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849526/1238303) and then I just added this:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel/IOFactory');
if (!class_exists('PHPExcel/IOFactory')) {
    throw new CakeException('Vendor class IOFactory not found!');
}
```

No luck.

And I've also tried calling it by using `public $helpers = array('PHPExcel','PHPExcel/IOFactory');` in my Controller, but this just asked for a helper which didn't exist. So that also gave me no luck.

**What do you want from us?**

Any assistance in getting this to work really. I have tried what I thought would be the logical ways to include IOFactory, but have had no success. Could someone please show me how to get PHPExcel's IOFactory to work?

Comment: what is the exact path to your PHPExcel files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming your folder structure is like this

```
App
    Vendor
        PHPExcel
            PHPExcel.php
            PHPExcel
                IOFactory.php
```

you should use

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel', array('file' => 'PHPExcel'.DS.'PHPExcel.php'));
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel_IOFactory', array('file' => 'PHPExcel'.DS.'PHPExcel'.DS.'IOFactory.php'));
```

Comment: Is this now in my loadEssentials function?

Comment: Awesome, this works. Also an update: I never called the function loadEssentials in my createMasterFile function.

Comment: @arilia The `file` paths in the code example do not match the assumed folder structure, or vice versa.

Comment: @ndm yes, sorry. I forgot another PHPExcel folder. DarkRanger edit is right

Answer (score 1):

put this line on top of the page

App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel', array('file' => 'excel/PHPExcel.php'));

plz change vendor path.